# Where/How is generated the html code of vsftpd?

Tags: linux, ftp, vsftpd

I mean the html code generated when you get into ftp://yourserver...  I tried to google it with no luck, not found in the project webpage either. I'd like to modify that code to do it more mobile friendly.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a browser to load an FTP directory then the HTML page will be generated **by the browser** from the directory listing.

For example, see [this part of the source code for Google Chrome](https://chromium.googlesource.com/apps/ftp/+/master/Prototype/FTPUI.js).

Comment: I thought it was generated on the server side... I need to do another approach to the problem. Thank you